# HIVE - Getting ALL columns of the table with COUNT(*) with DISTINCT values

Tags: sql, group-by, hive, count, distinct

I have the table below called Current_Table
[image]

I want to get the output that is,

1. The Column personalemailtrim to be DISTINCT
2. The column Occurrences must be over Count >1
3. Order by the column personalemailtrim

My Query so far build is wrong in many levels, Group by cant with DISTINCT and also using Count(*) doesnt give me any results with Group my etc....

```
SELECT id,
       personalemailtrim,
       personworksatnumberofbsbs,
       region,
       district,
       branch,
       num,
       countofapptsatbsb,
       COUNT(personalemailtrim) occurrences
  FROM Current_table
 GROUP BY id,
          personalemailtrim,
          personworksatnumberofbsbs,
          region,
          district,
          branch,
          num,
          countofapptsatbsb
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
 ORDER BY personalemailtrim
```

Any help provided is really appreciated . I tried several breaking down code methods but i am stuck on this

further to elaborate , The expected output should look like below

[image]

As you can see the,

1. Occurrences are > 1
2. personalemailtrim is now DISTINCT

Comment: It's unclear what you mean ...

Comment: Sure, Added more to the question to elaborate

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by personalemailtrim order by id) as seqnum
      from Current_table t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1 and occurrences > 1;
```

This assumes that occurrences is the same for each `personalemailtrim`, which is consistent with your data and with your question.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I just ran the query and came up with no results at all infact results was  = 0. This is the same error I got when I ran my code too

Comment: @YJG . . . Given the code in your question, this will definitely return rows 100 and 102.  If you care to set up a db<>fiddle with your code, I can demonstrate this.